# Union axiom in ZF+ur(elements) - example

Tags: set-theory

I am reading this:

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo-Fraenkel-Mengenlehre#ZF_mit_Urelementen

in particular "Vereinigungsaxiom"!!

and I thinking:

"if $K:=\{e,g,f,\{a,b\},\{c,d\},\{z,g\}\}$, with $e,g,f$ are ur-elements (and $K,\{a,b\},\{c,d\},\{z,g\}$ are sets), then $\bigcup K=\{a,b,c,d,z,g\}$

is correct?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have correctly interpreted the Vereinigungsaxiom as it is given in that article.

Comment: @Garnak: You're welcome!

Comment: therefore $\bigcap K = \emptyset$, is correct?

Comment: @Garnak: Yes, that's right.

Comment: M.Scott, if $\bigcup K= \emptyset $ then $ \forall T \in K(T \text{ is not set }\vee T=\emptyset \vee T=\{\emptyset\})$, is correct?

Comment: @Soviet: Not quite: if $K=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$, then $\varnothing\in\bigcup K$, since $\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\}\in K$, so $\bigcup K\ne\varnothing$. You want simply $$\forall T\in K(T\text{ is an urelement}\lor T=\varnothing\}\;,$$ because you want every member of $K$ to be an object that has no members.

Comment: M.Scott, of course.. thanks so much! :)

Comment: @Soviet: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The axiom of union is not changed by adding atoms (unlike the axioms of extensionality, replacement, and foundations).

So if $K$ is a set then $\bigcup K=\{x\mid\exists y\in K\text{ such that }x\in y\}$. If there are atoms in $K$, they do not have elements, so it works out just fine.

Comment: is correct also $\bigcup K:=\{x | x \in y \wedge y \in K\}$??

Comment: But $y$ in your comment is not quantified. So the definition is not good. If you quantify over $y$, it should be the same as I wrote.

Comment: okok of course... ;)